# Mongodb: db.collection.copyTo() and eval() have been deprecated. What's the alternatives?

Tags: mongodb

I find that [db.collection.copyTo()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/) and [eval()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) have been deprecated since 3.0. But I do not find what can be instead.

What's the alternatives?

Comment: you can use mongoimport and mongoexport

Comment: @gypsyCoder what for db.eval() ?

Comment: But, mongoimport and mongoexport are not programmability. I want to use python code to copy collection.

Comment: I asked the same question in Mongo-User group. This may help you : https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/mongodb-user/iOBfh1mZXpw/QW83aRUrNqQJ

Comment: For small collections, this worked as a `copyTo()` equivalent: `db.source_collection.find().forEach( function(doc) { db.dest_collection.insert(doc); } );`.

Comment: @duozmo you should put your comment as proposed solution

Answer (score 12):

For a server-side solution you can use aggregation...

```
db.getCollection('source')
    .aggregate([
        { $out: 'destination' }
    ]);
```

Comment: I would suggest to also consider `$merge` instead of `$out` as it offers a more flexible behavior and doesn't necessarily requires you to lose the data on the target collection: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#comparison-with-out

Comment: This is actually the official solution: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/reference/compatibility/#std-label-compatibility

Answer (score 4):

Per [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/iOBfh1mZXpw) on the MongoDB Group.

> The alternative is to implement the equivalent queries/operations using the normal MongoDB query language and client driver API

So that would mean writing your queries in a client environment (e.g. Node.js) and execute them that way. If run on the server connecting to localhost, they should pretty quick, although probably not as quick as using `eval`.

The rationale for the being deprecated is outlined in this ticket.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17453

Comment: Note that Node.js may not be a good solution if you are going to use a distributed database. Same thing happen with Eval(). A good denormalization is the best in this cases.

Answer (score 2):

Create a mongodump of that collection, do mongorestore to a separate or new collection.

This wont stop read/write or wont lock the collection.

```
mongodump --db db-name --collection collection-name --archive=collection-name.archive
```

or save as json both works

If saved as archive, to restore

```
mongorestore --db db-name --collection collection-name --archive=collection-name.archive
```