# Is mongo --eval() command line argument going to be deprecated too in MongoDB 3.x?

Tags: mongodb, eval, deprecation-warning

Following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474059/mongodb-db-collection-copyto-and-eval-have-been-deprecated-whats-the-alte/33870017?noredirect=1#comment55505547_33870017) about MongoDB 3.x deprecating the eval() function (as it should), I was wondering if there are any plan to also deprecate the availability of --eval() command line argument, like :

```
mongo --eval('db.getCollection("aaa").count();')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it's going to be deprecated. There is not deprecation warning when using `mongo --eval=`.

The deprecation was about MongoDB command [`db.eval()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.eval/) while `mongo --eval=` is a shell command -- i.e. an instruction to execute the passed code in the interpreter, which you can run otherwise manually in it.

Comment: The fact that there is no depreciation warning is indeed a clue, you're right.